# Eclipse / PyDev Stop button not working with OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid error

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, windows-10, pydev

I have the following Eclipse version on Windows 10:

```
Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
Build id: 20200910-1200
```

I am using PyDev along with it.

In my code I am using selenium to make a number of url calls (web scraping).  When it happens that a particular url is not present or at least not present in the way most of the urls I am reading are, I get the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\foobar\eclipse-workspace\WeatherUndergroundUnderground\historical\BWI_Fetch.py", line 44, in <module>
    main(city, month_date, start_year, end_year)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\eclipse-workspace\WeatherUndergroundUnderground\historical\BWI_Fetch.py", line 22, in main
    driver.get(city_url);
  File "C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror
Exception ignored in: <function Popen.__del__ at 0x0000019267429F70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 945, in __del__
    self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
  File "C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1344, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

When I get this particular error, eclipse is still running and pushing the red stop button does not work to end the program.  I can usually use the red stop button for just about any other python program I have written, but this code/error seems to hang things.  How can I end the process from within the Eclipse application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the stack trace is not really related to PyDev, so, the stack trace error is only really fixable in Selenium/Python (the error says that it's trying to access a process which is already dead on the `__del__`).

Now, related to the reason why PyDev wasn't able to kill it, I think that you probably have some process which spawned a subprocess and is not reachable anymore because the parent process died and thus it's not possible to create a tree to kill that process from the initial process launched in PyDev.

The actual code which does this in PyDev is: https://github.com/fabioz/winp/blob/master/native/winp.cpp#L208

I think that it should be possible to use the windows api to create a JobObject and then AssignProcessToJobObject and on kill also kill the JobObject  so that it kills all associated processes so that things are setup in a way that that this doesn't happen, but this isn't currently done.

As a note, usually I have an alias for: `taskkill /im python.exe /f` (which will kill all the `python.exe` processes running in the machine) and it's what I usually use in such cases, so, if something like that happens I just kill all the python.exe processes in the machine.

Although note that if you spawned some other process... say, `chrome.exe` -- in that process tree, that process must also be killed for the initial shell that launched python to be really disposed.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception ignored in: <function Popen.__del__ at 0x0000019267429F70>
```

...implies that the builtins module was destroyed before running `__del__` in process of garbage collecting.

Hence `PyDev` is no more able to communicate with the relevant python modules. As a result *Stop* button isn't functioning and raises the error:

```
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

Comment: If I go into Process Explorer and kill the relevant python tasks, Eclipse will still be oblivious to this it seems.  So is there a feature request to be made somewhere, perhaps a PyDev issue?

Comment: @demongolem Check this [Python issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue19021)